# Is there a way to check for number of routes in a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say you have a router setup like this in React, is there a way to check/get the number of routes in this component while writing tests using Jest and Enzyme? In this example, it should return 3 because the PrivateRoute uses Route under the hood. I'm not looking at using an external plugin though

```
<Router history={history}>
    <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute exact path='/' component={Component1} />
        <Route path='/register' component={Component2} />
        <Route path='/login' component={Component3} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import MyCompo from '../MyCompo';
import PrivateRoute fom '../PrivateRoute';

describe('<MyCompo />', () => {
  it('should have 3 routes', () => {
    const renderedCompo = shallow(<MyCompo />);

    expect(renderedCompo.find(Route)).toHaveLength(2);
    expect(renderedCompo.find(PrivateRoute)).toHaveLength(1);
  })
})
```

Comment: I've tried this and it fails. The length is 0 for Route and 1 for PrivateRoute